# Upload multiple versions(ex: 2.5 & 3.0) of the extension as single zip file in JED

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, extension-update

I have an Joomla extension for both v-2.5 & v-3.0 in JED. After updating the v-3.0 extension locally, I uploaded it into JED. I see that there is written_

```
For multiple versions of the extension (ex: one for 2.5 and one for 3.x) zip both together with all modules & plugins you distribute in the same package and put UNZIPFIRST in the zip name.
```

As far as I understood I have created my folder directory in following way_

```
UNZIPFIRST.zip  
 |
 |--2.5
 |    |
 |    |--language
 |    |--packages
 |    |     |
 |    |     |--com_revechat.zip
 |    |     |--plug_revechat.zip
 |    |--pkg_revechat.xml
 |--3.0
 |    |
 |    |--language
 |    |--packages
 |    |    |
 |    |    |--com_revechat.zip
 |    |    |--plug_revechat.zip
 |    |--pkg_revechat.xml
```

Inside pkg_revechat.xml_

```
<files folder="packages">
    <file type="component">com_revechat.zip</file>
    <file type="plugin" group="system">plug_revechat.zip</file>
</files>

<languages folder="language">
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.pkg_revechat.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

After uploading UNZIPFIRST.zip when to try to download the v-3.0 extension then downloads the older copy(not updated extension).

Could anyone say about my folder structure, is it correct or need to modify? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] while you wait for support.

Comment: I think the direct children need to be zip files. Therefore try making `2.5` and `3.0` zip files instead of directories

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just now I tried making `2.5` and `3.0` as zip files. But still downloading previous version files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case joomla, extensions are uploaded into the clients site. From JED client site is redirected. So don't need to upload extension in above way. Just upload it in your website and share that link for download.